# Client don't send data more than once

Tags: c, sockets

Hello I am trying to lean C Socket Programming for myself and recently I got stuck on this problem, I created the server it works good but I believe client has some problem because after first interrogation to server second time is not working anymore like hes stuck in an infinite loop no matter what numbers I type. Basically my application is working like this, client connect to server, and he receive a menu to get a picture and a text file ( not implemented yet ), client select 1 option, server respond and so on until quit option is selected.

```
    /* This is accept loop from server */
    while(1)
    {
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        if((new_fd = accept/* expression */(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Server-accept() error");
            continue;
        }


       printf("Server: Got connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));

        //Server sends this
        char msg[100] ="\nWelcome\n1.Get picture.\n2.Get text file.\n3.Quit\n";
        send(new_fd,msg,sizeof(msg),0);

        if((recv(new_fd,buf,12,0)) == -1)
        {
          printf("Didn't receive the data from client\n");
        }else
        {
          printf("I got this from client: %c\n",buf[0]);
          char *customMsg;
          switch (buf[0]) {
          case 49:
          customMsg ="Picture sent.";
          send(new_fd,customMsg,50,0);
          break;
          case 50:
          customMsg ="Text file sent.";
          send(new_fd,customMsg,50,0);
          break;
          case 51:
          customMsg ="Goodbye.";
          send(new_fd,customMsg,50,0);
          close(new_fd);
          printf("Server-new socket, new_fd closed successfully...\n");
          break;
          }
        }

     }

    /* This is the client from connect phase */

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect()");
        exit(1);
    }
    int endTransmission = 0;

    if((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("recv() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';
    printf("Response from server: %s", buf);
    do
    {
      char *valToSend;
      printf("Enter your option: ");
      scanf("%s",valToSend );
      send(sockfd,valToSend,1,0);

      recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);


      printf("\nThis is what I got back from server:\n%s\n", buf);

      if(*valToSend == 3)
         endTransmission = 1;
    }while(endTransmission != 1);

    printf("\nClient-Closing sockfd\n");
    close(sockfd);
```

Comment: Perhaps your client blocked inside the `recv()` call, waiting for data to be sent by the server?

Comment: All three of the usual suspects:(

Comment: `char *valToSend; scanf("%s",valToSend );` Where exactly the data is scanned into?

Comment: Could you please share the error log

Comment: There is no error log, its just stuck like Jeremy Friesner says in recv() I believe...but why first time works fine, as expected and second time it get stuck ? This problem I can't see it

Answer (score 1):

> I believe client has some problem because after first interrogation to server second time is not working anymore …

It is the server which *has some problem*, namely the repeated call of `accept` while the connection is still established. The solution is to put an inner loop around the sending of the server's menu and the response to the client's selection, e. g. by changing

```
        send(new_fd,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
```

to

```
        while (send(new_fd, msg, sizeof msg, 0) > 0)
```

(without `;`).